# Saving Standalone Table to .mmpk file

Tags: arcgis-pro, mobile, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java, mobile-map-package

How do I save a Standalone Table to an .mmpk file ?

I try save Standalone table to mmpk file, but i didn`t get it in mobile app
[image]

I tried get tables from this object in android app, but "GetTables" property return   zero size.

```
mapPackage = new MobileMapPackage(generateFileMapFoder() + "/mobile_map.mmpk");
                // load the mobile map package asynchronously
                mapPackage.loadAsync(); 

mapPackage.addDoneLoadingListener(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {mapPackage.getMaps().get(0).getTables()})
```

Comment: Two questions 1) what version of the runtime are you using and 2) what version of Pro created the mmpk?